# How to use expansion board through COM Express with QNX OS?

Tags: qnx

I have a carrier board and an expansion board which can be connected to the carrier board through the COM Express. I want to know what settings has to be made on the carrier board as well as the expansion board to use the functionalities of the expansion board through the COM Express.

For now, I have just connected both board and tried to use the peripheral from the expansion board but it didn't work. I am using QNX OS. There's no BSP available for the expansion board from QNX's side.

The setup works with Yocto OS after adding the layer of expansion board BSP.